# Tail recursion with List + .toVector or Vector?

Tags: scala

```
  val dimensionality = 10
  val zeros = DenseVector.zeros[Double](dimensionality)

  @tailrec private def specials(list: List[DenseVector[Int]], i: Int): List[DenseVector[Int]] = {
    if(i >= dimensionality) list
    else {
      val vec = zeros.copy
      vec(i to i) := 1
      specials(vec :: list, i + 1)
    }
  }

  val specialList = specials(Nil, 0).toVector
  specialList.map(...doing my thing...)
```

Should I write my tail recursive function using a List as accumulator above and then write

```
specials(Nil, 0).toVector
```

or should I write my trail recursion with a Vector in the first place? What is computationally more efficient?

By the way: specialList is a list that contains DenseVectors where every entry is 0 with the exception of one entry, which is 1. There are as many DenseVectors as they are long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sur what you're trying to do here but you could rewrite your code like so:

```
type Mat = List[Vector[Int]]

@tailrec
private def specials(mat: Mat, i: Int): Mat = i match {
  case `dimensionality` => mat
  case _ => 
    val v = zeros.copy.updated(i,1)
    specials(v :: mat, i + 1)
}
```

As you are dealing with a matrix, Vector is probably a better choice.

Comment: I updated the question, now it should be clear what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare the performance characteristics of both variants:

- `List`: prepending takes constant time, conversion to `Vector` takes linear time.
- `Vector`: prepending takes "effectively" constant time (*eC*), no subsequent conversion needed.

If you compare the implementations of `List` and `Vector`, then you'll find out that prepending to a `List` is a simpler and cheaper operation than prepending to a `Vector`. Instead of just adding another element at the front as it is done by `List`, `Vector` potentially has to replace a whole branch/subtree internally. On average, this still happens in constant time ("effectively" constant, because the subtrees can differ in their size), but is more expensive than prepending to `List`. On the plus side, you can avoid the call to `toVector`.

Eventually, the crucial point of interest is the size of the collection you want to create (or in other words, the amount of recursive prepend-steps you are doing). It's totally possible that there is no clear winner and one of the two variants is faster for `<= n` steps, whereas the other variant is faster for `> n` steps. In my naive toy benchmark, `List/toVecor` *seemed to be* faster for less than 8k elements, but you should perform a set of well-chosen benchmarks that represent your scenario adequately.